# GA with virtual pageviews, goal does not increase

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, pageviews

I have created a goal on Google Analytics like this

**Type: Destination**

**Destination URL: /successful-registration**

But on the app, when I send pageview event like this from the JS

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/successful-registration')
```

I don't see any changes in the Goals report on GA, it is still at 0. Do you know why? I have been waiting for a while so I don't think it is because of latency, something must be incorrect here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really suited for SO - webmasters would be better... but with that said, how long ago did you create the goal vs how long ago did you do the pageview? Goals are not retroactive. Additionally, are the dates selected in the reporting match when you sent your data? Finally, any filters that might be blocking the request? Do you see the page in the pages report?

Comment: Thanks, I should move this to webmaster forum. I even create the goal 2 hours before trying to send event to GA. The dates and filters are correct though

Comment: You do not need to wait - realtime view has a "conversion" menu item that reports goal conversions immediately.